# How do I hide breadcrumb menu in Team Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, breadcrumb

Hello I would like to know how i can hide breadcrumb menu in team site.

Comment: Please share some snap that would be more helpful !!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

1. Via CSS: which I don't prefer most (because even you hide it but it actually renders from server causing a minor performance) but easy to implement, If you are    using out of the box master page, then use `.ms-breadcrumb-box{ display: none; }` as css. Note, this will also hide you page titles if you use it master css.
2. Remove Breadcrumb for Master Page: In you master page search for div having class name `ms-breadcrumb-box` and remove the SharePoint controls contains 'Breadcrumb' in their ID. This will hide the breadcrumb navigation form page and increase your performance a bit.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.ms-breadcrumb-box{ { display: none; }
span#.ms-breadcrumb-box{ margin-left: 20px; }
</style>

Comment: I am trying this code above but it don't work

Comment: where you put this css, in master page or in script editor web part?

Comment: Just saw, if you copy pasted above code then you had written `.ms-breadcrumb-box{ { ` which is causing problem. It must be `.ms-breadcrumb-box{ display: none; }`

Comment: It has been hidden however how do i push it up.

Comment: you need to hide the complete wrapper. The `.ms-breadcrumb-box` is not the only div in wrapper. It has multiple siblings, actually the `#s4-titlerow` div contains four child divs. Because you are hiding only one div, it is not going move `#content` div up. Also the `#content` div is outside the `#s4-titlerow` div so, in order to achieve what you want, you may need to redesign the master page.

Answer (score -1):

FYI, for similar situations like mine it will need to be:

`.ms-Breadcrumb
 {
    display: none;
 }`

I didn't expect the upper case B to make such a difference :)